# Change TFS setup default installation directory

Tags: team-foundation-server

I want to do an automated TFS (2013) setup on 150+ build servers.

The OS support guys insist on installing 3rd party apps on "D:\Apps" instead of the default location, but leave the default installation path in the registry unchanged (changing that isn't supported my Microsoft anyway).

Now I'm looking for a way to do that through the TFS Setup command line (tfs_server.exe).

It must be possible in principle, because you can do it in GUI mode, but there seems to be no command line option for it. Does anyone know whether it is possible through a configuration file or an environment change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same on official Microsoft forum ([Automate upgrade of TFS Build servers on custom directory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8baf0b26-8c79-4d3d-b58f-e36c98b48c91/automate-upgrade-of-tfs-build-servers-on-custom-directory?forum=tfsadmin#8baf0b26-8c79-4d3d-b58f-e36c98b48c91)), but the answer was negative.

At the moment, there is no way to specify a different directory in an unattended install.